# Python argparse groups confusion

Tags: python, argparse

I want to create an "installer" program that you can call like this:

```
installer install PROGRAM
installer install PROGRAM MY_DIR
installer list
```

I'm trying to instruct argparse so that you *must* call installer with either `install` or `list`. list requires no arguments while install requires a program to install and optionally a destination directory. This is what I have so far:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="installer")
parser.add_argument('action', choices=['install', 'list'], help='install|list', type=str)

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

install_group = subparsers.add_parser('install', help='install program')
install_group.add_argument('program_name',    help='name of the program to install', type=str)
install_group.add_argument('destination_dir', help='where to install the program', nargs='?', type=str)

list_group = subparsers.add_parser('list', help="list available programs")

args   = parser.parse_args()
```

The problem is that the help generated doesn't seem to reflect this:

```
# python installer.py --help

usage: installer [-h] {install,list} {install,list} ...

positional arguments:
  {install,list}  install|list
  {install,list}
    install       install program
    list          list available programs

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
```

The help for `python installer.py install --help` is just the same. No mention of destination_dir or program_name

Any help?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question, it jusy gives the same result.

Comment: You can put the `subparsers` in an argument group by giving it a `title`: parser.add_subparsers(title='actions',description='a description', help='a help')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `action` argument is confusing `argparse`. Remove that line; you only need the two `subparsers` for the CLI to behave correctly (including refusing anything other than `install` or `list`).

Global help:

```
C:\Python34>python installer.py --help
usage: installer [-h] {install,list} ...

positional arguments:
  {install,list}
    install       install program
    list          list available programs

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
```

Install help:

```
C:\Python34>python installer.py install --help
usage: installer install [-h] program_name [destination_dir]

positional arguments:
  program_name     name of the program to install
  destination_dir  where to install the program

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
```

Unsupported argument:

```
C:\Python34>python installer.py hello
usage: installer [-h] {install,list} ...
installer: error: invalid choice: 'hello' (choose from 'install', 'list')
```

---

Note that you *could* still have got the subparser help, by passing one of the accepted values to `action` *then* naming a subparser:

```
C:\Python34>python installer.py install install --help
usage: installer {install,list} install [-h] program_name [destination_dir]

positional arguments:
  program_name     name of the program to install
  destination_dir  where to install the program

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
```